# Summation to Infinity in Both Directions and Absolute Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If I have a sum $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}$, I say that this equals $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = -N}^{N} a_{n}$ when "the summation is absolutely convergent". I know that if we have $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n}$, then the series is said to be absolutely convergent if $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} |a_{n}| < \infty$. But how is absolute convergence defined when we have $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}$?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|a_n|<\infty$?

Comment: My guess is that the condition is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |a_n| < \infty$, where the LHS is defined as the limit $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N |a_n|$.

Comment: Well, you're justified in splitting up $\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n$ as $\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{-1} a_n+\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n$, so...

Comment: It should be pointed out, however, that the limit $$\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} a_n$$ can exist without absolute summability: For a very simple example take $a_k = 1/k$ if $k \neq 0$ and $a_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sum is absolutely convergent, then the limit is independent of the order of summation.  In particular, when a sum has only positive summands, then either it converges in any order or it does not converge in any order.

$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent iff for every bijection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$, $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{f(n)}$ is.
But this is the same as saying that $\lim\sum_{-N}^N|a_n|<\infty$ which is the same as saying that there is $M\in\mathbb R$ such that for every finite set $S\subseteq\mathbb Z$, $\sum_{n\in S}|a_n|<M$.

In general, if $I$ is an arbitrary index set, a sum $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$, with all $a_i$ real numbers, is absolutely convergent if there is $M\in\mathbb R$
such that for every finite set $S\subseteq I$, $\sum_{i\in S}|a_i|<M$.
In this case $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ is defined to be $\sup\{\sum_{i\in S}a_i:S\subseteq I\mbox{ is finite }\}$.